# Difference between source and ./ execution of linux scripts

Tags: linux, csh

csh:

```
set a=0 
echo "a is $a"
```

when i do ./my_script.csh output is:

```
a is
```

when i do source my_script.csh output is:

```
a is 0
```

Why is it so . As i know that ./ execution uses new shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if variable "a" is set in your current shell:

```
set | grep '^a='
```

Remember that once you source script to your current shell, 
all it's global variables are there until unset or you exit the current shell.
You may want to start a new shell, source the script, end exit shell to perform valid tests.

I don't know the context of your problem, but you may want to export some key variables to have their copies in every subprocess.

Answer (score 4):

That's right, ./my_script.csh starts a new shell, and uses the #! that you should have at the top of the file to select which shell to run (which **should** be csh in this case).

source my_script.csh runs the script in the current shell.

If the script is incorrectly run in, for example, the bash shell, set a=0 is not the syntax for setting an environment variable in bash, so the code won't work as you expected, because you're using the wrong shell.

Take a look at the #! at the top of the file. Is it correct?

Comment: But i tried without it and used echo "$SHELL" in both case it shows /bin/csh . Why is it so

Comment: I didn't even know you could have Linux scripts without #! at the top! I've learned something new today. But I don't know about them.

Comment: I guess when you don't use a shebang-line, /bin/sh is used, which is usually linked to bash.